# Spring boot + GRPC Http2Exception

Tags: spring-boot, http2, grpc, paas, grpc-java

I am trying to set up GRPC server with spring boot. My VIP is pointing to server on port 8443. I am trying to connect to the GRPC server on my vip from my local GRPC client.

Is there anything that I am missing while following the approach GRPC with spring boot ?

```
2017-05-29 10:11:30.549  INFO 12796 --- [           main] n.d.s.a.grpc.server.GrpcServerLifecycle  : gRPC Server started, listening on address: 0.0.0.0, port: 8443
2017-05-29 10:11:30.971  INFO 12796 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https)
2017-05-29 10:11:30.979  INFO 12796 --- [           main] c.a.IntentProcessorGroup1Application     : Started IntentProcessorGroup1Application in 26.45 seconds (JVM running for 27.737)
2017-05-29 10:11:41.736  WARN 12796 --- [-worker-ELG-3-1] io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler         : Connection Error

io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 160301008e0100008a03039bda7533eee4bee56f87bd4a42
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:85) ~[netty-codec-http2-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
```

Comment: please let me know if any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The reason I was getting this error is because I was not starting my grpc server on TLS configuration correctly.
The issue is resolved now and details can be found here : https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter/issues/44